# how to calculate a path to take into account the stroke width?

Tags: android, canvas, graphics

I'm painting a dynamic line on a Canvas object using

```
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

I have a rather large stroke width. And the stroke width is distributed equally to both side of the path. So if I set the B point of my path on the edge of my view, pixels are painted outside of my view.

[image: screnshot 1]

Additionally, the path continues to point C. And this path may have even more rotation, pushing to top-most pixel even higher!

How do I calculate the position of point B to take account of the stroke size on a path from A to B and from B to C?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Where do you want point B to be?